# Constraint layout beta 4 - fragments don't work

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-constraintlayout

Note 0:
At least try this code and let us know if it works for you or not. Because in theory this should work, but it doesn't

Note 1:
There is no error in this code it simply doesn't work if you are on any Constraint layout above alpha-7. However, I'm putting the logcat.

**MainActivity.java:**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        FragmentManager mFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction mFragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        Fragment fragment = new stupid();
        mFragmentTransaction
                .add(R.id.main_activity, fragment, "stupid")
                .addToBackStack("stupid")
                .commit();

    }

}
```

**activity_main.xml:**

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_activity"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:text="Hi 1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="13dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="18dp"
        android:id="@+id/textView" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Stupid.java:**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class stupid extends Fragment {


    public stupid() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_stupid, container, false);
    }

}
```

**fragment_stupid.xml:**

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="xxx.xxxxxxx.xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxx.stupid">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_blank_fragment"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="136dp" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Log:**

```
12-04 10:28:30.965 12609-12609/xxx.xxxxxxx.xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxx I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
12-04 10:28:31.015 12609-12609/xxx.xxxxxxx.xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxx I/InstantRun: Instant Run Runtime started. Android package is xxx.xxxxxxx.xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxx, real application class is null.
12-04 10:28:31.299 12609-12609/xxx.xxxxxxx.xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxx W/art: Failed to find OatDexFile for DexFile /data/data/xxx.xxxxxxx.xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxx/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_1-classes.dex ( canonical path /data/data/xxx.xxxxxxx.xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxx/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_1-classes.dex) with checksum 0xe09cbad0 in OatFile /data/data/xxx.xxxxxxx.xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxx/cache/slice-slice_1-classes.dex
12-04 10:28:31.512 12609-12609/xxx.xxxxxxx.xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxx I/LoadedApk: No resource references to update in package common
12-04 10:28:31.512 12609-12609/xxx.xxxxxxx.xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxx I/LoadedApk: No resource references to update in package com.brit.swiftdark
12-04 10:28:31.809 12609-12609/xxx.xxxxxxx.xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxx W/ResourceType: For resource 0x01030224, entry index(548) is beyond type entryCount(29)
12-04 10:28:31.809 12609-12609/xxx.xxxxxxx.xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxx W/ResourceType: For resource 0x01030224, entry index(548) is beyond type entryCount(29)
12-04 10:28:31.843 12609-12609/xxx.xxxxxxx.xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxx W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
12-04 10:28:31.947 12609-12726/xxx.xxxxxxx.xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxx D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
12-04 10:28:31.956 12609-12609/xxx.xxxxxxx.xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxx D/Atlas: Validating map...
12-04 10:28:31.996 12609-12726/xxx.xxxxxxx.xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxx I/Adreno: QUALCOMM build                   : 065751b, 
                                                                            Build Date                       : 04/15/15
                                                                            OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.25.03.07
                                                                            Local Branch                     : 
                                                                            Remote Branch                    : quic/LA.BF64.1.2.1_rb2.9
                                                                            Remote Branch                    : NONE
                                                                            Reconstruct Branch               : AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.BF64.1.2.1_RB2.05.01.00.081.016 + 065751b +  NOTHING
12-04 10:28:32.003 12609-12726/xxx.xxxxxxx.xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxx I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
12-04 10:28:32.011 12609-12726/xxx.xxxxxxx.xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxx D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
12-04 10:28:32.069 12609-12609/xxx.xxxxxxx.xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxx I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@22f2f04f time:200835125
```

**Edit 1:**
Alpha-7
[image: Alpha-7 results]

Beta-4
[image]

Comment: 1) The log is useless, there's no error. 2) You haven't said what's your desired output. Show us how it looks now and how it looked before/how it's supposed to look. 3) What exactly do you expect is going to happen if you put a fragment with a constraint layout inside another constraint layout? Kinda defeats the purpose of a constraint layout anyway, no? 4) Use the layout designer in Android Studio and make sure you see your TextViews in the layout there.

Comment: 1) I stated that the log doesn't have an error already. I put it there because someone will come and ask why there is no log if I'm facing a problem.

Comment: 2) It is stated that the desired output is to make the code work. meaning, the layout will be created when you run the app. However, you are right, I should add pictures to show what is wrong and clarify. My bad :).

Comment: 3) you are right, but you can try with replace(), it doesn't work either.

Comment: 4) That is part of the problem, The Android Studio layout designer shows everything fine. However, when running this on an emulator or an actual device, it gives a white screen.

Comment: sorry, not a white screen ... it just doesn't show the fragment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to this post for an answer .... [ConstraintLayout 1.0.2 shows nothing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45226676/constraintlayout-1-0-2-shows-nothing/45228714#45228714)

I know this is both "This post and the linked post" are mine, also the answer. But I been looking for an answer for almost a year. I finally found that older versions of ConstraintLayout will, for some reason, be added on top of the activity. Newer versions of ConstraintLayout fragment will be put in back of the activity. or at least that's what it looks to me. That's why I'm saying make your activity transparent.